# Почему перескакивает ID в sql

Tags: ssms

Почему так ? При добавление записи перескакивает с 49 до 1043. Я понимаю что при удаление записи он не выдает id удаленной записи, но тут я вообще ничего не удалял

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У айдишника автоинкремент стоит? Если так, то удаляя записи айдишник не уменьшается, можно создать 100 записей, потом удалить все, потом снова добавлять и они начнутся от 101й.

Comment: Пока вы не приведете больше сведений, гадать можно очень долго. Как создавалась таблица, как описано данное поле, как работаете с ним, нет ли в базе дополнительных вычислений для этой таблицы и т.д. Если вы ничего не удаляли, то даже банально автоинкремент может иметь собственные настройки (начинать с 1043, а первые записи записаны в обход него).

Comment: Автоинкремент гарантирует только одно - то, что сгенерированное значение ранее не генерировалось. Всё. Ну плюс следствие из-за особенностей реализации - сгенерированное значение больше любого сгенерированного ранее. А вот отсутствия "дыр" в последовательности никто не обещал. Нужна непрерывная нумерация? заводите под неё отдельное поле и заполняйте его программно - с учётом многопоточности.

Comment: Скорее "identity jump issue" во время перезапуска SQL Server, при которой IDENTITY может перескочить на указанный размер кэша `IDENTITY_CACHE`. Для типа [int] по умолчанию стоит вроде 1000. Вот только отключение кэша может снизить производительность. Стоит помнить что IDENTITY дает только автоинкремент, а не последовательность.

Comment: Таблицы создавалась стандартно с помощью CREATE TABLE и у поля id стоит IDENTITY и Primary key, я понимаю, что автоинкремент стоит и если было удалено 100 записей, то следующая начнется с 101.  Мне просто интересно нормально ли это, что запись перескакивает вот  так. Вариант с размером кэша интересный. Т.е если отключение кэша может снизить производительность. Получается ничего с этим не сделать  и оставить всё как есть? Меня это волнует потому что INT имеет свои ограничение по диапазону. И что делать если Id дойдет до предела диапазона?

Comment: Был еще вариант сделать это программно. А если использовать тригеры  в sql? На сколько это рационально?